# Cross-query with IN/INTERSECT, INNER JOIN or EXISTS?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, exists

I'm working with IMDb data to find out full crew information of a number of chosen films.

I have a table called *movie*, where I isolated the films that fit my requirements, 476 rows in total, where *movie_id* is the unique identifier for each film.

I have a table called *crew_info*, which has columns *movie_id*, *person_id* and *role_id*.

As the first step I want to create a new table, isolating only those people who have worked on the films which exist in my *movie* table. I want to have a list of distinct people, so no duplicates even if the same person worked on a number of films from *movie*.

I can think of a few ways to do it, and not sure whether there is a difference/which one is better. First, I created a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    person_id INTEGER,
    person_name TEXT,
    person_birth INTEGER
);
```

Now I think I need to do one of the following:

```
INSERT INTO person (person_id)
    SELECT DISTINCT person_id
    FROM cast_info
    WHERE movie_id IN
    (
        SELECT movie_id
        FROM cast_info
        INTERSECT
        SELECT movie_id
        FROM movie
    );
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO person (person_id)
    SELECT DISTINCT person_id
    FROM cast_info
    INNER JOIN movie
    ON cast_info.movie_id=movie.movie_id;
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO person (person_id)
    SELECT DISTINCT person_id
    FROM cast_info
    WHERE EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT movie_id
        FROM cast_info
        WHERE cast_info.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        );
```

Later on I intend to UPDATE the table with *person_name* and *person_birth* values cross-queried from other relevant tables, using similar statements.

Would these expressions yield the same result or not? If not, which one works best?

Comment: where are you getting person_name and person_birth from?

Comment: @vkp There are two other tables, called _name_ and _person_info_, holding the respective information. Each relies on the same _person_id_ identifier. Didn't want to include them in this post to avoid making it too meaty, I imagine that I will have less problem figuring those out if I get past my initial confusion about these statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get the same results from all three.  I would recommend the `INNER JOIN`, as it's the simplest to write.  The gains in performance will be probably always be negligible, but queries 2 and 3 will require one less index scan. Query 1 will scan cast_info twice.

To update the table after, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE P
SET P.Person_Name = T.Person_Name
FROM Person P
INNER JOIN OtherTable T on T.Person_ID = P.Person_ID
```

And of course, it's always nice to run a `SELECT`, verify your columns, then change the first two lines to be an update and fire away with confidence.

```
SELECT P.Person_ID, P.Person_Name, T.Person_ID, T.Person_Name
FROM Person P
INNER JOIN OtherTable T on T.Person_ID = P.Person_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

This intersect is redundant

```
WHERE movie_id IN
    (
        SELECT movie_id
        FROM cast_info
        INTERSECT
        SELECT movie_id
        FROM movie
    );
```

I think the join is the most direct

```
INSERT INTO person (person_id)
SELECT DISTINCT person_id
FROM cast_info
INNER JOIN movie
ON cast_info.movie_id=movie.movie_id;
```

why?

```
CREATE TABLE person
( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

just use person_id as primary key

and use date for birthday